# M Code for conditional column to convert inches to cm conditionally

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I created a conditional column using dax programming to transform inches to centimeters. However, I must take place in `Transform Column`. I googled that it is `M Code`. Do you know how this code would look like in M Code? The intention is to create the column `conditonal_column` if `column_a` is `I` then `col_b` should be multiplied by 2.45. If it is `M` then do not make the multiplication.

```
conditional_column = IF(data[col_a] = "I", data[col_b] * 2.54, data[col_b])
```

This is my table

```
|col_a| col_b|
|-----|------|
| I   |0.4   |
| M   |0.6   |
| I   |0.12  |
| M   |0.18  |
```

Expected Result

```
|col_a| col_b| conditional_column|
|-----|------| ------------------|
| I   |0.4   |0.10               |
| M   |0.6   |0.6                |
| I   |0.12  |0.30               |
| M   |0.18  |0.18               |
```

Comment: Can you supply your sample data in copiable format and expected result?

Comment: Hello @DavidBacci, I dont know how to make it in a copiable format. I described the intention from the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column and type in the following:

```
if [col_a] = "I" then [col_b] * 2.54 else [col_b]
```

[image]